# Validation doesn't work as expected for related models in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I use one form to enter data for two models. When I save parent model (Tenant) the child model (User) also gets saved, but only if I don't validate tenant_id in User model. If I do `validates :tenant_id, presence: true` in User model then validation error "Users tenant can't be blank" is displayed. Any ideas why?

Tenant model:

```
class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :tenant
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users    

  before_validation do 
    self.status = 0 
    self.name = name_orig.upcase 
    email.downcase!
  end

  validates :name_orig, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }

  validates :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  validates :status, presence: true

end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :tenant, inverse_of: :users
  validates_presence_of :tenant

  before_validation do 
    self.status = 0
    self.email = email.downcase
  end

  VALID_USERNAME_REGEX = /\A\w+\s?\w*\z/i
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 },
                    format: { with: VALID_USERNAME_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

  validates :tenant_id, presence: true

  validates :status, presence: true

end
```

Tenant controller:

```
class TenantsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @tenant = Tenant.new
    @tenant.users.build
  end

  def create        
    @tenant = Tenant.new(tenant_params)
    @tenant.save

    if @tenant.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
      redirect_to @tenant   # redirects to tenant profile
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  private

    def tenant_params
      params.require(:tenant).permit(:name_orig, :email,
          users_attributes: [:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation])
    end

end
```

Signup form:

```
<%= form_for(@tenant) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/tenant_error_messages' %>

  <%= f.label :name_orig, "Company name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name_orig, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :email, "Company e-mail" %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.fields_for(:users) do |u| %>

    <%= u.label :name, "User name" %>
    <%= u.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= u.label :email, "User e-mail" %>
    <%= u.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= u.label :password, "Password" %>
    <%= u.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= u.label :password_confirmation, "Password confirmation" %>
    <%= u.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please update your question with form code.

Comment: Why do you want to enter data for two models at once ?
(You don't need `validates :tenant_id, presence: true` since you already have `validates_presence_of :tenant`)

Comment: @Pavan, I added the signup form

Comment: @HoloHokkaido, when first user of tenant A is signing up then I need data for both: tenant and its user. Later, when second, third, etc user will signup for the same tenant A then only each new user data will be saved with reference to tenant_id in each user's record.

Comment: @HoloHokkaido, I removed `validates_presence_of :tenant`, but this didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using nested attributes and saving both models at the same time, you cannot validate `tenant_id` for `user` since they will be persisted in a transaction.

Because `tenant` is not persisted, it does not yet have an id. Since it does not have an id, there cannot be `tenant_id` for `user`.

In this case validating `tenant_id` is pointless, because you cannot persist a `user` without `tenant` since `user` is being built on top of `tenant`. So if your user will be persisted, then a corresponding tenant will also be present.

In the case you mentioned, where users can sign up on an independent form -

To validate that a tenant will be associated in the create action use:

```
tenant = Tenant.find_by(params[:tenant_id])
user = tenant.users.build(user_params)
```

instead of

`user = User.new(user_params)`

This way you will not have any orphan children

Comment: Thank you @Kkulikovskis!